# error install laravel v 5.4 with composer in ubuntu

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

**hey a get error when install laravel v-5.4**

a get error this :

> The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2016%24e217873bdc8408956b33b1eb317ad1182d3a82fde9a746cc5e7def6135696f96.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)
>   http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0)
>     - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0): Loading from cache
>   Created project in blog
>   @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check `https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.`md#degraded-mode for more info
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1].
```

please help me for finish this problem. I tried but but no result.

Comment: Why don't you first at least install the `ext-dom` package to begin with: `sudo apt-get install php-xml`. After that you can visit the provided link and start troubleshooting that way. If you are still have problems AFTER you have visited the link and tried the solutions provided then you let me know.

Comment: it looks like phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom

Comment: i think the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7 or later, you can install `ext-dom` by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml // for PHP 7
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml // for PHP 7
```

Comment: but I checked php version. I alredy have php with that version.

Comment: do I need to install it again

Comment: Not necessarily.